The target is a binary and can't have any crate-types set
I am writing a contract in RUST for staking and unstaking DOT tokens I have used ink , cargo and sustrate to do this . This is my lib.rs :
lib.rs:
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

#[ink::contract]
mod polkadot_staking_exchange {
    use ink::prelude::vec::Vec;
    use ink::storage::Mapping;
    use scale::{Decode, Encode};

    #[derive(Encode, Decode, Clone, Default)]
    #[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(scale_info::TypeInfo))]
    pub struct StakeInfo {
        amount: u128,
        start_time: u64,
        is_active: bool,
    }

    #[derive(Encode, Decode, Clone, Default)]
    #[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(scale_info::TypeInfo))]
    pub struct UnstakeRequest {
        amount: u128,
        request_time: u64,
    }

    #[ink(storage)]
    pub struct PolkadotFlexiStakingExchange {
        owner: AccountId,
        treasury_address: AccountId,
        user_stakes: Mapping<AccountId, Vec<StakeInfo>>,
        unstake_requests: Mapping<AccountId, Vec<UnstakeRequest>>,
        interest_rate_history: Vec<(u128, u64)>,
        cooling_period: u64,
        fee_percentage: u128,
    }

    impl PolkadotFlexiStakingExchange {
        #[ink(constructor)]
        pub fn new(
            owner: AccountId,
            treasury_address: AccountId,
            cooling_period: u64,
            initial_fee_percentage: u128,
        ) -> Self {
            let mut instance = Self {
                owner,
                treasury_address,
                user_stakes: Mapping::default(),
                unstake_requests: Mapping::default(),
                interest_rate_history: Vec::new(),
                cooling_period,
                fee_percentage: initial_fee_percentage,
            };

            instance
                .interest_rate_history
                .push((50000000000000000, Self::env().block_timestamp()));

            instance
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn set_treasury_address(&mut self, treasury_address: AccountId) {
            self.treasury_address = treasury_address;
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn update_interest_rate(&mut self, new_rate: u128) {
            self.interest_rate_history
                .push((new_rate, Self::env().block_timestamp()));
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn stake(&mut self, amount: u128) {
            let caller = Self::env().caller();
            let value = Self::env().transferred_value(); // Correct method is transferred_value()

            assert!(value >= amount, "Insufficient stake amount sent");

            let stake_info = StakeInfo {
                amount,
                start_time: Self::env().block_timestamp(),
                is_active: true,
            };

            let mut stakes = self.user_stakes.get(caller).unwrap_or_default(); // Use get method for Mapping
            stakes.push(stake_info);

            // Insert or update stakes for the caller
            self.user_stakes.insert(caller, &stakes);
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn request_unstake(&mut self, amount: u128) {
            let caller = self.env().caller();
            let request = UnstakeRequest {
                amount,
                request_time: self.env().block_timestamp(),
            };

            // Retrieve current requests or default to an empty vector
            let mut requests = self.unstake_requests.get(caller).unwrap_or_default();

            // Push the new unstake request
            requests.push(request);

            // Insert the updated requests back into the Mapping
            self.unstake_requests.insert(caller, &requests);
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn process_unstake_requests(&mut self) {
            let caller = Self::env().caller();

            if let Some(requests) = self.unstake_requests.get(caller) {
                for request in requests.iter() {
                    // Use `checked_add` to prevent overflow
                    let request_time_with_cooling = request
                        .request_time
                        .checked_add(self.cooling_period)
                        .expect("Overflow occurred");

                    // Assert cooling period has passed
                    assert!(
                        self.env().block_timestamp() >= request_time_with_cooling,
                        "Cooling period has not passed"
                    );

                    assert!(
                        self.env().balance() >= request.amount,
                        "Contract does not have enough balance"
                    );

                    Self::env()
                        .transfer(caller, request.amount)
                        .expect("Transfer failed");
                }

                self.unstake_requests.remove(caller);
            }
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn get_total_staked(&self, user: AccountId) -> u128 {
            if let Some(stakes) = self.user_stakes.get(user) {
                stakes.iter().map(|s| s.amount).sum()
            } else {
                0
            }
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn withdraw(&mut self, amount: u128) {
            assert!(
                Self::env().balance() >= amount,
                "Insufficient balance in contract"
            );
            Self::env()
                .transfer(self.owner, amount)
                .expect("Withdraw failed");
        }
    }
}

and this is my Cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "polkadot_staking_exchange"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
ink = { version = "4.0.0-beta", default-features = false }

scale = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
scale-info = { version = "2.3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"], optional = true }

[dev-dependencies]
ink_e2e = { path = "../../crates/e2e" }

[lib]
name = "polkadot_staking_exchange"
path = "src/lib.rs"
crate-type = ["cdylib", ]

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "ink/std",
    "scale/std",
    "scale-info/std",
]
ink-as-dependency = []
e2e-tests = []

the lib.rs is inside src folder . I keep getting this error when I run cargo contract build "the target polkadot_staking_exchange is a binary and can't have any crate-types set (currently "cdylib")" why?
